# check if a List Contains instances of classes in a particular order using hamcrest

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, assert, hamcrest

Hi I am writing a unit test where I need to assert that a list contains objects of multiple classes in a specific order. I want to do this using hamcrest.

Right now I am asserting it like -

```
assertThat(actual, hasItem(isA(A.class)));
assertThat(actual, hasItem(isA(B.class)));
assertThat(actual, hasItem(isA(C.class)));
```

Here I want to test that the items are in order A->B->C. I have tried writing it like -

```
assertThat(actual, contains(isA(A.class), isA(B.class), isA(C.class)));
```

but this is not supported, is there a way to achieve this with hamcrest matchers?

Comment: Which version are you on? It seems to be working for me with version 1.3.

Answer (score 2):

Use [this method](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.0.0.0/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#containsInRelativeOrder-org.hamcrest.Matcher...-t-.-):

```
public static <E> Matcher<java.lang.Iterable<? extends E>> containsInRelativeOrder(Matcher<? super E>... itemMatchers)
```

From the docs:

> Creates a matcher for Iterables that matches when a single pass over the examined Iterable yields a series of items, that each satisfying the corresponding matcher in the specified matchers, in the same relative order. For example:
>   assertThat(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), containsInRelativeOrder(equalTo("b"), equalTo("d")))

In your case, it could be like this:

```
assertThat(actual, containsInRelativeOrder(isA(A.class), isA(B.class), isA(C.class)));
```

Available since Hamcrest 2.0.0.0.